# Unable to find iPad Pro iOS 10 device using Cordova for emulation

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, ios-simulator

I'm trying to run my Cordova application on **iPad Pro 12.9 inch** (for getting screenshots to upload to App Store) but I don't see the iPad pro simulator in the cordova list command i.e. `cordova emulate ios --list`.

That Simulator is available/installed in my system. Googling the issue took me to the issue [ios-sim#197](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim/issues/197) so I upgraded it's latest version but I'm still unable to launch using the command line.

Here are the output of the commands:

`cordova emulate ios --list`:

```
Available iOS Simulators:
    iPhone-5, 10.1
    iPhone-5s, 10.1
    iPhone-6, 10.1
    iPhone-6-Plus, 10.1
    iPhone-6s, 10.1
    iPhone-6s-Plus, 10.1
    iPhone-7, 10.1
    iPhone-7-Plus, 10.1
    iPhone-SE, 10.1
    iPad-Retina, 10.1
    iPad-Air, 10.1
    iPad-Air-2, 10.1
    Apple-TV-1080p, tvOS 10.0
    Apple-Watch-38mm, watchOS 3.1
    Apple-Watch-42mm, watchOS 3.1
    Apple-Watch-Series-2-38mm, watchOS 3.1
    Apple-Watch-Series-2-42mm, watchOS 3.1
```

`ios-sim showdevicetypes`:

```
iPhone-5, 10.1
iPhone-5s, 10.1
iPhone-6, 10.1
iPhone-6-Plus, 10.1
iPhone-6s, 10.1
iPhone-6s-Plus, 10.1
iPhone-7, 10.1
iPhone-7-Plus, 10.1
iPhone-SE, 10.1
iPad-Retina, 10.1
iPad-Air, 10.1
iPad-Air-2, 10.1
iPad-Pro--9-7-inch-, 10.1
iPad-Pro, 10.1
Apple-TV-1080p, tvOS 10.0
Apple-Watch-38mm, watchOS 3.1
Apple-Watch-42mm, watchOS 3.1
Apple-Watch-Series-2-38mm, watchOS 3.1
Apple-Watch-Series-2-42mm, watchOS 3.1
```

I tried various combinations like:

```
cordova emulate ios --target="iPad-Pro, 10.1"
```

but nothing worked and the error I got:

> Device id for device name "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)" and runtime "iOS 10.1" could not be found, or is not available.

I'm running this on **Mac Sierra** with **xcode 8**.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12125

Comment: It was a bug. It has been fixed. You can delete this post because it isn't a real question

Comment: Thanks, sure. I'll delete it